# Spring Data JPA project, how to limit the amount of nested objects? @OneToMany

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on a small Spring REST API project. I have two classes that represent 2 tables in my database. I have a @OneToMany mapping in the object that I want to retrive data from. Right now I retrive ALL the nested objects, but what I want is to be able to limit the amount of nested objects by its int datestamp variable (which is an epoch declared as "utcs" in my class). I was naively thinking that the CrudRepoitory could help me with that but now I understand I was wrong. What I was hoping to be able to do in my repository was something like this:

```
@Repository
public interface TypeRepository extends CrudRepository<Type, Integer> {
    List<Type> findByDataUtcsGreaterThan(int utcs);
}
```

This is the JSON structure I want and how it looks right now. But how do I limit the amount of Data objects?

```
[
    {
        "typeKey": "Queue",
        "uomId": 1,
        "data": [
            {
                "value": 11,
                "utcs": 1605840300
            },
            {
                "value": 15,
                "utcs": 1605840360
            },
            {
                "value": 22,
                "utcs": 1605840420
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "typeKey": "Unroutable",
        "uomId": 1,
        "data": [
            {
                "value": 196,
                "utcs": 1605840300
            },
            {
                "value": 196,
                "utcs": 1605840360
            },
            {
                "value": 196,
                "utcs": 1605840420
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The (Type) object class with the nested object   @OneToMany

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SYSTEMSTATSTYPE")
public class Type {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "TYPEKEY")
    private String typeKey;
    @Column(name = "UOMID")
    private int uomId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "type", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Data> data = new ArrayList<>();

    public Type() {
        super();
    }

    public Type(String typeKey, int uomId) {
        this.typeKey = typeKey;
        this.uomId = uomId;
    }

    // Getters and setters
}
```

The (Data) object class   @ManyToOne

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SYSTEMSTATSDATA")
public class Data {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "VALUE")
    private int value;
    @Column(name = "UTCS")
    private int utcs;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "TYPEID")
    private Type type;


    public Data() {
        super();
    }

    public Data(int value, int utcs, Type type) {
        super();
        this.value = value;
        this.utcs = utcs;
        this.type = type;
    }
    // Getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a possibility directly with the annotation, and using EAGER fetching is in most cases not a good idea anyway. I think you have to build the logic yourself with a custom query, either fetching only the 2 Data objects (something as described here https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-limit-query-results), or a join getting you Type and Data all together right away.

Answer (score 0):

That's not directly possible. You could do dedicated select queries for each `Type` object or maybe use something like [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) which has native support for [limiting collection elements](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/#limit-mapping).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Type.class)
public interface TypeDto {
    @IdMapping
    Integer getId();
    String getTypeKey();
    int getUomId();
    @Limit(limit = "5", order = "utcs DESC")
    Set<DataDto> getData();

    @EntityView(Data.class)
    interface DataDto {
        @IdMapping
        Integer getId();
        int getValue();
        int getUtcs();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`TypeDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, TypeDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
@Repository
public interface TypeRepository extends CrudRepository<Type, Integer> {
    List<TypeDto> findByDataUtcsGreaterThan(int utcs);
}
```